# Eclipse linkedResources to android asset subdirrectory does sometimes not work

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, assets

We have an android project writtten in Java and use the standard Eclipse with ADT plugin. We use android assets and for some reason we have to have a subdirectory of assets (not all assets) in another location. Standard filesystem soft links are not good solution for us because it is not git+linux - git+windows portable (some of our developers use linux and some windows). So we tried to use eclipse link in .project file

```
<linkedResources>
  <link>
    <name>assets/defaults</name>
    <type>2</type>
    <locationURI>$%7BPARENT-2-PROJECT_LOC%7D/somedir/somesubdir</locationURI>
  </link>
</linkedResources>
```

This looks like when we browse assets in Eclipse. The problem is that when we run the project, assets in the linked directory are sometimes found and sometimes not (FileNotFoundException). It looks like ADT sometimes ignores the linked directory and sometimes not. (2 days ago it did not worked, yesterday did, today does not...) It is a probably a google bug in ADT. It seems linke of the asset root works always, link of asset subdirectory only sometimes. Is there any solution? Thanks.